# Heroku states "Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Heroku states "Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile" on the inital commit.

I've already changed my Gemfile so that sqlite is used in development and pg is used in production mode. My database.yml is added to the .gitignore file. Are there any places where I have to change sqlite to pg?

Thanks in advance

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-rails',
                          :github => 'anjlab/bootstrap-rails',
                          :branch => '3.0.0'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem "json"
gem "nokogiri"
gem "leaflet-rails"
gem "mapbox-rails"

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:   https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :production, :staging do 
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'    
end

group :development do 
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem "binding_of_caller"
end


# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously ran

```
bundle install --without production
```

the solution to my problem was to install also the production gems. What my production gems have to do with a "specified sqlite3 adapter" I don't understand at all.